# Resize an image with php without a library

Tags: php, image, resize

I've a this piece of code.

It charge an image to my web server and save the name into my sql.

All works except the resize time. I found the function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["AddPhoto"])) {

    if ($_FILES["AddPhoto"]["error"] > 0) {
        $newImgMessError = $MYCARDEDIT0058;
    }
    else {
        $fileName = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['size']/1024;
        $fileType = $_FILES['AddPhoto']['type'];
        $fileExtension = end(explode(".", $fileName));

        if(($fileType == "image/gif" || $fileType == "image/jpeg" || $fileType == "image/pjpeg" || $fileType == "image/png" || $fileType == "image/x-png") && $fileSize < 1000000) {

            $newFileName = md5(date('u').rand(0,99)).".".$fileExtension;
            $imagePath = "assets/picts/".$newFileName;




// THIS PART DO NOT WORK            
// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imagePath);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
$imagePath = imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);            








            $result = @move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $imagePath);

            $request = mysql_query("SELECT ".$TypeField."Images FROM $TypeFiche WHERE $TypeId='$cardId'");
            $var2 = mysql_fetch_array($request);

            mysql_query("UPDATE ".$TypeFiche." SET `".$TypeField."Images`='".$var2[$TypeField.'Images'].$newFileName.",' WHERE $TypeId='$cardId'");

            if (!$result) {
                $newImgMessError = $INSCRIPTION0074." <b>".$fileName."</b>. ".$INSCRIPTION0075."<br />";
            }
            if ($result) {
                $newImgMessError = $INSCRIPTION0076." <b>".$fileName."</b> ".$INSCRIPTION0077."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Errors? No file? Your server get killed?

Comment: If I remove the script (the one is not indented), the image is on my server but without resize. When the script is here, I have these errors : Division by zero - Invalid image dimensions - imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Are you sure that `$imagePath` contains an right (if possible absolute) path to the uploaded file?

Comment: Yes for sure cause when i remove the un indented code it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to move the file to the new directory before you can resize it. Put your resize below this line:

```
$result = @move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $imagePath);
```

Otherwise the resize code tries to access a file which doesn't exist yet.

2. You have to write the new image as file out, so replace that line

```
 $imagePath = imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

with this

```
imagejpeg($image_p, $imagePath, 100);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php